# excel power pivot and power query

Tags: excel-2010, powerquery

I need to create a table that will calculate the percent of one column from another column. The problem is that those column are calculated by pivot table so i cant use the calculated filed on them( it gives me only the fields that are on the table connected to the pivot table).
I have tried to do this calculation by taking the pivot table to the power query but when i update the database it does not update the calculation in the power query

what is the most simple way to do this calculation?
thanks!
liron

Answer (score 0):

If Power Query is reading cells from your pivot table in an Excel workbook, then you'd need to first refresh the pivot table and then Power Query.

Alternatively, Power Query can directly read from most databases. Why not just do the pivot directly against the database table from Power Query, and then the percent calculation will always see the latest data.